# Cómo puedo recorrer la triangular inferior de una matriz en diagonal?

Tags: java, matrices

*La idea es que solo imprima las diagonales, he logrado imprimir la triangular pero recorriendo las columnas*

```
System.out.println("triangular");

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        if (i >= j) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+"\t");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de lo que deseas hacer

Comment: suponiendo que tengo un matriz 3x3, se debería imprimir los elementos de las posiciones 1,1; 2,2; 3,3; 2,1; 3,2; 3,1 en ese orden

Comment: y no notas las progresiones matematicas en eso?

Answer (score 0):

Si para recorrer la diagonal del centro, `i` tiene que ser igual a `j`.

```
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    System.out.print(matriz[j][j] + " ");
```

Para recorrer otra diagonal que esté más abajo, solo tienes que sumarle una constante a `j`.

```
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    if (j < n)
        System.out.print(matriz[j + i][j] + " ");
```

**Problema:** `j` más la constante puede ser una posición inválida. Hay que verificar que sea válida antes.

```
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    if (j + i < n)
        System.out.print(matriz[j + i][j] + " ");
```

Entonces para imprimir cada diagonal habría que iterar `i`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        if (i + j < n)
            System.out.print(matriz[i + j][j]);

    System.out.println("\n");
}
```